# mkdir that overwrites any existing directory

Tags: windows, command-line, mkdir

If I try to run `mkdir build` to create a `build` directory, if the directory already exists, this error is thrown: `A subdirectory or file build already exists.`. I need to delete and overwrite this directory. What is the command for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can delete the build directory with

```
rd /s /q build
```

or

```
if exist build rd /s /q build
```

Comment: For best results, run this command twice.  It will sometimes fail if, e.g., Windows Search happens to be indexing that directory at just the wrong time.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to create directory only if it does not exist
If it exists, nothing to do

Below worked great in the bat file:

```
if not exist someDir1 mkdir someDir1
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to use the `mkdir` command to do that natively (though if you were will to do a bit more scripting, it would be possible).

A simple alternative is the following command in powershell:

`New-Item path -type directory -force`

Where `path` is something like `C:\users\name\build`

For more on `New-Item` see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

Comment: I can't execute powershell as I'm calling this from a rake script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `rd` command to remove the directory. You have to ensure the directory is empty first though.

Comment: This throws an error if there are elements in the directory.

Answer (score -3):

This command can help:

```
mkdir -p a & rm -r a & mkdir a
```

[This my answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170856/1698859)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using Windows **not** Unix.